# A smart video "conversion" tool that remuxes instead of converting where possible

Tags: video

Often when I want to convert files sent to me in a mkv container, I wish to convert them to mp4 to be compatible with my Apple devices. More often than not, the video stream in the mkv is already h.264 and it is only the audio stream(s) that need to be converted to mp3 or aac to be placed in an Apple-compatible mp4.

Is there any tool out there that is:

- Free
- The output is specified generically in terms of a container and codecs, not at specific bitrates (mp4, h.264 and mp3)
- If the input file has a compatible video stream of any bitrate it is simply copied and all others are converted
- Batch compatible (either scripted or a batch-enabled GUI)
- Any OS, but Mac or Linux is preferred

I realize that a mkvtoolnix/ffmpeg/mp4box toolchain is *capable* of doing all of this with the correct parameters, but is there any tool that automates the process?